# Unir arreglos en PHP

Tags: php, array, cakephp

Tengo una consulta que me trae todos los usuarios de la base de datos, pero necesito hacer una comparación con otra tabla en la cual no hay relación. Lo hago todo mediante php pero necesito unir los datos de la otra tabla con la primera, es decir tener todo.

Codigo:

```
$instructores = array();

$instructoresActivos = $this->Usuario->query("select * from usuarios");
$fechas = $this->Usuario->query("select * from fechas");
foreach($instructoresActivos as $instructorActivo){
     $instructores = array_merge($instructorActivo,$instructores);

}
```

El problema es que solo me trae el primer registro y no se por que. ¿Alguna solucion? Gracias.

Comment: puedes adjuntal el esquema de las tablas usuarios y fechas?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando realizas la instrucción

```
$instructoresActivos = $this->Usuario->query("select * from usuarios");
```

$instructoresActivos no es un array, es lo que en PHP creo que se llama recorset.

para obtener un array que contenga a todos los instructores deberías escribir la siguiente instrucción

```
$arrayInstructoresActivos=$instructoresActivos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Ya solo quedaría unirlo con el otro array

```
foreach($arrayInstructoresActivos as $instructorActivo){
 $instructores = array_merge($instructorActivo,$instructores);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría una consulta de ambas tablas no con SQL directamente sino con los objetos que proporciona CakePHP

```
$users = $this->Users->find('all')->toArray();
$other = $this->OtherTable->find('all')->toArray();
```

Y luego los combinaría

```
$instructores = array_merge($users, $other);
```

Espero que esto le funcione!

Saludos.